# Cubing a Minterm

Tags: arithmetic, binary

I've just been going over some stuff I should actually already know - and I've come to a question that has really stumped me, (my math skill are lacking) and I don't actually know where to begin on it.

> Which of the following minterms is $$m_3(A,B,C)$$
>   1. ¬ABC
>   2. A¬BC
>   3. AB¬C
>   4. ABC

I'm less interested in the answer, and more in 'how' the answer is achieved

Thanks - Apologies for the janky formatting

---

Edit:

I've just been given the 'answer' after I got it incorrect (I guessed) of -

> 3 = 0112, thus the first variable A must be complemented and the other
>   two (B and C) must remain non-complemented.

Now I'm even more confused!

Comment: What is the definition of $m_3(A,B,C)$ in use from your notes/text?

Comment: Please see if my answer below explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems more likely that the method to find $m_k(A,B,C)$ is to express $k$ in base $2$ (with enough digits padded by leading zeros if necessary to have a total of three digits, since three variables) and then associate the digits to $A,B,C$ in order. So $3$ in base $2$ being $11=011$ we have "off,on,on" i.e. $A$ complemented and $B,C$ not complemented.

You may have need of a different notation $3=(011)_2$ to match this up with the explained answer.

Note that when a number is expressed as a base 2 string of 0's and 1's, the usual notation is to enclose the 0,1 string in parentheses and put a subscript 2 afterwards. So here instead of writing $3=0112$ it is more standard to write $3=(011)_2$. Then the three digits in order are $0,1,1$ which one matches up with $A,B,C$ in that order, so that $A=0,B=1,C=1$ which using 0 for false and 1 for true gives (not A)BC.